# Chained comparisons in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

Python [supports chained comparisons](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in): `1 < 2 < 3` translates to `(1 < 2) and (2 < 3)`.

I am trying to make an SQL query using SQLAlchemy which looks like this:

```
results = session.query(Couple).filter(10 < Couple.NumOfResults < 20).all()
```

The results I got were not as expected. I've turned the engine's `echo=True` keyword, and indeed - the generated SQL query only included one of the two comparisons.

I can't find any documentation that explicitly says this is forbidden. I assumed that if this type of expression is supported in Python, it should be supported in SQLAlchemy as well.

Why doesn't this work? I have one possible solution in mind (shared in answers), but will be glad to hear other opinions.

Comment: Related: [How do chained comparisons in Python actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754726/how-do-chained-comparisons-in-python-actually-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Python actually evaluates something akin to this:

```
_tmp = Couple.NumOfResults
(10 < _tmp and _tmp < 20)
```

The `and` operator is unsupported in SQLAlchemy (one should use `and_` instead).  And thus - chained comparisons are not allowed in SQLAlchemy.

In the original example, one should write this code instead:

```
results = session.query(Couple).filter(and_(10 < Couple.NumOfResults, 
                                            Couple.NumOfResults < 20)).all()
```

Comment: That's exactly right. In python, `a > b > c` is special syntax. `3 > 2 > 1` is `True`, while `(3 > 2) > 1` is `False`. There's no way for sqlalchemy to behave intuitively in both cases without having parser-level information about your code.

Comment: That's exactly wrong.  In the chained comparison, Python guarantees *not* to evaluate `Couple.NumOfResults` twice.

Answer (score 4):

SQLAlchemy won't support Python's chained comparisons. Here is the official reason why from author Michael Bayer:

> unfortunately this is likely impossible from a python perspective. The mechanism of "x < y < z" relies upon the return value of the two individual expressions. a SQLA expression such as "column < 5" returns a BinaryExpression object, which evaluates as True - therefore the second expression is never called and we are never given a chance to detect the chain of expressions. Furthermore, the chain of expressions would need to be detected and converted to BETWEEN, since SQL doesn't support the chained comparison operators.
>   Not including the detection of chains->BETWEEN part, to make this work would require manipulation of the BinaryExpression object's `__nonzero__()` value based on the direction of the comparison operator, so as to force both comparisons. Adding a basic `__nonzero__()` to BinaryExpression that returns False illustrates that it's tolerated pretty poorly by the current codebase, and at the very least many dozens of "if x:" kinds of checks would need to be converted to "if x is None:", but there might be further issues that are more difficult to resolve. For the outside world it might wreak havoc.
>   Given that the appropriate SQL operator here is BETWEEN which is easily accessible from the between operator, I don't think the level of bending over backwards and confusing people is worth it so this a "wontfix".

See details at: 
https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/1394/sql-expressions-dont-support-x-col-y